# It appeared error when I import one table into impala table

Tags: impala

load data inpath `/opt/truevideo/msisdntest.csv` into table `ps.aaa_msisdn_list`
ERROR:

```
 AnalysisException: INPATH location
 hdfs://hacluster/opt/truevideo/msisdntest.csv does not exist
```

Actually, the table had existed in hadoop. I don't know why can't load the csv file.

```
(
 hadoopc1h3:/opt/truevideo # ll
 total 17701932
 -rwxrwxrwx 1 omc  users   12641118 Dec 17 09:30 a123.txt
 -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    223 Dec 21 11:36 msisdntest.csv
)
```

Anyone can help me to solve this issue? many thanks.

Comment: Do you have `/opt/truevideo` mounted? I don't remember hdfs files can be listed like that.